# Could 007 have just had Goldfinger arrested for imprisoning and almost killing him in Switzerland?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, goldfinger

In *Goldfinger*, 007's Mission was to prove Goldfinger is a criminal and get him behind bars. But midway through the movie, Goldfinger almost killed 007 on the laser table and then kidnaps him and imprisons him.

But the movie makes it clear James Bond could escape at any point he wanted to, by either simply running off or using the GPS tracker to alert Felix.

So why not just escape and have Goldfinger arrested? I'm pretty sure kidnapping people is going to get you a few years.

Comment: Two thoughts: Goldfinger has more than enough money to bribe any authorities, and his associates may have carried out the plan even if he were arrested

Comment: Third thought: Bond is a secret agent, Goldfinger *knows* he's a secret agent, and I'm sure Goldfinger would be more than willing to blow Bond's cover at any criminal proceedings that might ensue.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that was the mission? I haven't seen the movie in decades but wikipedia says, "Bond's objective is determining how Goldfinger smuggles gold across countries' borders." Aside from that, when has the plot of a Bond movie ever been "Bond finds villain, rings the cops. The End"? There is such a thing as narrative imperative & that device in Bond was always 'Bond blows up the secret hideaway'.

Comment: Not related to the question but GPS did not exist when *Goldfinger* was released.

Comment: @ToddWilcox GPS didn't exist, but the British Secret Service launched their satellites on the hush-hush using the Black Knight, launched from Woomera (Black Knight ... a long way from home)

Comment: @Tetsujin:  Most Bond villains are "legitimate" public figures, not wanted on sight by the police, exactly so that there's a sensible reason to have a movie instead of calling a SWAT team.  It would be a lot less good if the only reason for *not* getting backup was a massive ego on Bond's part.  We want that ego *and* a practical reason (local law enforcement in their pocket, or nothing illegal enough to get them taken down and put away permanently, or like here, other goals.)  It's better if suspension of disbelief isn't required in the first place.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Because that is not Bond's mission.

The mission is to establish how Goldfinger is illegally transferring gold out of the country so the government can seize his assets.

> As yet, we have failed to discover
> how he transfers his gold overseas,
> and Lord knows we've tried.
>
> If your department can establish
> that it is done illegally, then the
> Bank could institute proceedings to
> recover the bulk of his holdings.

Even if Bond reported the kidnap and attempted murder to the authorities, *he has no proof of this happening*, it would not accomplish his primary mission.

Comment: Who cares about Bond's life, as long as we get the gold back?

Comment: But Bond's mission is already completed. It was finished when he overhears Goldfinger explaining to Mr Ling how the bodywork of his car is 18-carat gold and that he makes six trips a year to the continent. So the first part of the film is over: Bond can head off, report to M and leave it to the authorities. And he tries to. Instead, Bond discovers (stumbles upon) Masterton, tries to escape, gets caught and enters the second part of the film: Operation Grand Slam and all that goes with it. (As an aside, I can't see how Bond could escape when he liked, which OP says, but that's not this point.)

Answer (score 4):

### Secret Agents don't like having to stand up in court

Bond's career as a secret agent is over if he has to give testimony over his kidnapping, even though having Goldfinger arrested would buy them a lot of time to uncover the *how* of the gold transfer.

Instead he has to find secondary evidence to start proceedings. Similar to how Al Capone's downfall was his [tax evasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Capone#Tax_evasion).

### International cases are complicated.

Goldfinger is rich, even before he fiddles the price of gold. Money can buy lawyers, and a failed court case, say where Bond is accused or trespassing threatens to make any later legal action against Goldfinger much more difficult.